# Sveltekit: Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs on one table, but not others

Tags: postgresql, prisma, sveltekit

Running into a bit of an odd issue.  I'm using sveltekit and prisma with postgres.  I'm loading data like so in my +page.server.ts file:

```
import type { PageServerLoad } from "./$types"
import { prisma } from "$lib/server/prisma"

export const load = (async () => {
    const response = {
        companies: await prisma.companies.findMany(),
        barges: await prisma.barges.findMany(),
        parish_tax: await prisma.parish_tax.findMany()
    }
    return { feed: response };
    }) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

The companies and barges tables load fine.  The parish_tax portion throws the following error:

```
Error: Data returned from `load` while rendering /dashboard is not serializable: Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs (data.feed.parish_tax[0].parish_rate)
```

Here are my table columns:

companies

[image]

parish_tax

[image]

Trying to understand why I'm receiving this error, if anyone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into this same issue (I have a Decimal field and that's a Prisma class). One could loop through the results and create an array of new objects with the specific fields converted, but that would be very inefficient. I asked about this on Discord but didn't get a response. Seems like this is something most people would run into, no?

Comment: @ccraig my research brought me to [this piece](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6008#issuecomment-1227359874) of information written by Rich Harris himself.  I'm not smart enough to figure out how to use devalue to solve my problem, and I hope someone can explain.  Surely this problem can't be so specifically unsolved with sveltekit?  Why wouldn't it just work for decimals?  As an amateur developer it sure adds a barrier to adopting sveltekit.

Comment: "The one limitation of devalue is that it doesn't support custom classes like ObjectId or Prisma.Decimal" so I guess there's no need for you to lear devalue anyways. I see he doesn't use Prisma, so maybe there isn't a clean solution due to Prisma's use of Decimal.js. I'm going to ask around on Discord and report back.

Comment: what about [this?](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6008#issuecomment-1227510231)

Comment: I didn't try it but I guess it could work. You also have to add this ["recipe"](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6008#issuecomment-1225829043) to superjson for it to work with Decimal

Comment: So I decided to use `return { JSON.stringify( my_results: my_results) }` and then on +page.svelte  `const my_results = JSON.parse(data.my_results) as MyResultType[]`. It's not as pretty, but less code than the superjson stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to only return POJOs (plain-old-javascript-objects) from the load function in SvelteKit.
Your response data is not serializable, because your `parish_tax` objects contain an attribute `parish_rate` which is not a POJO and therefore non serializable. I am not sure what the exact type of the `parish_rate` attribute is, my guess is probably a class which can not be serialized. The solution is to simply cast this attribute to a type which is serializable before returning it from the load function.

Comment: Thank you for the response, though unfortunately this doesn't tell my anything I don't already know.  It seems that my load function has no problem with any of the other columns being returned except for the parish_rate column.  I'm not sure why this numeric type would be unserializable, though I will admit I don't know much about serialization.

There is nothing different between the companies data and parish_rate data being returned except for this different data type.

I have tried to use structuredClone and json.parse/stringify but this doesn't work either.

Comment: SvelteKit now has https://github.com/Rich-Harris/devalue included. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Prisma.Decimal (could be adapted for other classes)

```
export const makeJSSafe = (/** @type {any}} */ obj) => 
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
        const tag = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj[k]).toStringTag;
        let value;
        switch (tag) {
            case '[object Decimal]':
                value = obj[k].toNumber();
                break;
            default:
            value = obj[k];
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        acc[k] = value;
        return acc;
    }, {});
```

And call like this:

```
const myData = await prisma.rate.findMany({
});
// returns array of objects
myData = 
[
   {name: 'monthly', rate_value: (object Decimal type),
   {name: 'annual', rate_value: (object Decimal type),
];

const safeData = myData.map( obj => makeJSSafe(obj));
// result
safeData = [
   {name: 'monthly', rate_value: 0.02,
   {name: 'annual', rate_value: 0.085,
];
```